# Searching nxn pixels in entire image with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

As described in the title i am trying to find the best way of iterating through a grayscale image and creating a `nxn` kernel to scan through the pixel values. The primary objective is to create a min/max filter, and extend it to a custom median filter.

I have already created a hardcoded solution for 3x3, but theres alot of code and expanding this to a 5x5 will be a painful process.

I was wondering if OpenCV has any functions that can manage such task?

Can [minMaxLoc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=minmaxidx#minmaxloc) somehow be used with a rectangle mask?

EDIT: What i basically want is following

1. Copy a rectangel from `image` to `subImage`.
2. Determine/analyze min or max value of pixels in `subImage`.

EDIT (test):

```
    for(int y = 1; y < image.rows - 1; y++) {
        for(int x = 1; x < image.cols - 1; x++) {
            if(int(image.at<uchar>(x,y)) == 0) {
                double maxValue = 0;
                Rect roi(y-1,x-1,3,3);
                Mat image_roi = image(roi);
                minMaxLoc(image_roi, NULL, &maxValue, NULL, NULL);
                if (maxValue > 0) {
                    image_new.at<uchar>(x,y) = uchar(maxValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are [these](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html) functions what you are looking for?

Comment: @Hammer, which function are you refering to?

Comment: I was referring to erode and dilate, they set all values in a kernel to the maximum or minimum value in that kernel.  Smooth also has a median option which I think does what you are looking for.

Comment: I would look at the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html), specifically at the BaseFilter and FilterEngine classes. It looks like you may be able to make a custom subclass to do what you need.

Comment: @Aurelius, i am realising that my problem might be easier than i assumed. Region of interest (ROI) is similiar to what i need, but this function is from an older API. Is there anyway that i can cut out a piece (rectangel) from my image for further analysis?

Comment: I have made an edit to describe short what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a rectangular region of interest in the C++ API is very easy.

```
cv::Mat subImage = image(cv::Rect(upper_left_x,upper_left_y,ROI_width,ROI_height));
```

should allow you to process `subImage` however you need.

If what you need is a median filter, OpenCV has that functionality too:

```
cv::medianBlur(image, outputImage, n);
```

for an nxn filter. Further documentation for this function can be found at the link in my first comment above.

Comment: can you please review the code in my question? It was my attempt of using ROI, but it does not exactly end with the result i wanted.

Comment: Found the error. I had reversed x and y. Although i have problems in the border.

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of problems you are having 'in the border'?